# Referring library project .. gives NoClassDeffoundError for R files

Tags: android, android-library

I have a android library project which contains UI xml.
This lib contains R.java of its own.
I have the library stored inside libs folder.

When I try to refer this into a different application i get following error.

```
07-10 10:53:33.758: E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.libraryProject.R$drawable
```

Comment: Try cleaning all projects in Eclipse. Goto menu Project->Clean

Comment: did that several times. relaunch the application. Restarted the Eclipse.

Comment: Don't you have the jar file for this library?

Comment: yes... i do have it included in the libs folder of the main project.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not importing it the right way. There are two ways of importing android code into a project

- Jar file: Should not have any kind of resource, as of right know you will not be allowed to access it.
- Library project: You import the project into the workspace as a standalone app, and in the project that needs the library, reference it at Properties->Android->Library->Add.

Jar files are just zipped code. You can copy&paste into lib, and add them at the BUILD_PATH.
But library projects are reference. Is not gonna work if you just copy&paste the project into the libs folder, as you said.

It seems you're mixing both.